# Rails change default devise url

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to change the default rails url for user

current url => `users/sign_in`

new url => `/user/sign_in`

my current devise route is `devise_for :users`

how to get new url.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this into routes.rb -

```
as :user do
    get 'user/sing_in' => 'devise/sessions#new'
  end
```